# Send data to absolute URL with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, post

I have an HTML file with the URL `localhost/dir1/dir2/file.html`. In this file  I send data through jquery to the server.

```
$('#element').live("change", function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:  "localhost/dir1/dir3/file.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { esp: $(this).val() },
        success: function(result){
            $("#element2").html(result);
        }
    })
```

I get an error due to jquery send the data to `localhost/dir1/dir2/localhost/dir1/dir3/file.php` but I need send the data to `localhost/dir1/dir3/file.php`.
How can I do this?

Comment: have you tried adding the protocol to your url? `url: "http://localhost/dir1/dir3/file.php"`? (the `http://` part)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your url to:

```
   /dir1/dir3/file.php
```

This avoids hardcoding the protocol and server into your code.